# 'protractor' is not recognized as an internal or external command when installed locally

Tags: node.js, angular

I installed `protractor` in local folder using 'npm install protractor'. After installed complete I checked the version of protractor using `protractor --version`.

But it is gives error:

> 'protractor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file

How to solve this error?

Comment: Hi 

Did you get any solution of above issue. I am also facing this.

Answer (score 6):

I have a similar problem on Windows Server 2016. Following steps should resolve it:

**Make sure the installation is global.**

> npm install -g protractor

**Make sure npm is set in PATH environment variable. Go to "Edit environment variables for your system", Append the following line to the Path variable.**

> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm

Answer (score 1):

Try to run it locally by `npm run protractor`. Make sure you have required scripts in your **package.json**. A sample one is like below:

```js
    "scripts": {
        "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
        "protractor": "protractor ./e2e/protractor.conf.js",
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you install in local using
 `npm install protractor`
Your module will be installed only in your local directory.

You should use `npm install -g protractor` which will install the module in global path and made available as a environment variable. So that your machine will recognize it as a command.